# svn to git conversion: Correct remote ref must start with 'refs/' error

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, git-svn, svn2git

(I'm posting this question with the intention of answering it myself as I could not find the answer elsewhere. Hopefully it will help others who run into the same issue and it will help me next time I'm trying to do it.)

**The Challenge**

I want to convert an SVN repository to a locally hosted gitlab GIT repository and maintain history.

**The Setup**

Gitlab 8.5, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, subversion 1.8.8

**The Problem**

Initial attempts to convert from svn to git using git-svn or svn2git resulted in the following error.

**Error**

`svn-remote.svn: remote ref '//example.com:81/svn/myrepository/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk' must start with 'refs/'`

**What I've tried**

I've followed both guides in the external references below.

**External References used**

- http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/importing/migrating_from_svn.html
- http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

Comment: Had you tried in Linux or windows?

Answer (score 13):

1. Generate an authors.txt file. This will contain a mapping between your SVN users and your Gitlab users:

   - From an existing svn repository: `svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors.txt`
   - Otherwise, manually create it following this format:

     `oldSVNusername = newGitlabUsername <gitlabRegisteredEmailAddress@example.com>`
2. Create a temporary directory init SVN repo

   - `mkdir temp`
   - `cd temp`
   - `git svn init --no-metadata  http://username:password@example.com:81/svn/myrepository`
3. Configure git

   - `git config svn.authorsfile ~/authors.txt`
   - `git config --global user.name myusername`
   - `git config --global user.email myusername@example.com`
4. Grab the files and clone them into a new git repo

   - `git svn fetch`
   - `git clone . ../myrepository`
   - `cd ../myrepository`
5. Setup new repository in gitlab, make sure your user has access to it.
6. Add a remote gitlab repository

   - `git remote add gitlab gitlab.example.com:gitlab-group/myrepository.git`
7. Double check your configuration in `myrepository/.git/config` (especially the URL line)

   `[core]
      repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = true
       bare = false
       logallrefupdates = true
   [remote "origin"]
       url = /root/temp/.
       fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   [branch "master"]
       remote = gitlab
       merge = refs/heads/master
   [remote "gitlab"]
       url = http://gitlab.example.com/gitlab-group/myrepository.git
       fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gitlab/*
   [user]
       name = myusername`
8. Push it all upstream

   - `git push --set-upstream gitlab master`

Now you should have all the files and history converted to git and displaying in gitlab.

Comment: Of all the different procedures I found on the internet, this one actually worked on the 1st pass.  Others had errors, or unexpected results.

Comment: Glad it helped someone else!

Answer (score 8):

Removing the leading /slash works for me:

This will not work:

```
git svn clone "http://..." --prefix=svn/ --trunk=/trunk --branches=/branches --tags=/tags  --authors-file "authors-transform.txt" "C:\Temp\GitRepos"
```

This works:

```
git svn clone "http://..." --prefix=svn/ --trunk=trunk --branches=branches --tags=tags  --authors-file "authors-transform.txt" "C:\Temp\GitRepos"
```

Answer (score 1):

What it woked for me was deleting the .git directory and the run the next command  :

```
git svn clone --authors-file=authors.txt --no-metadata http://svn.companie.com/REP/mock/ -s mock
```